# Use i in variable r

Tags: r, loops

I want to use the `i` variable to loop over this piece of code, each iteration changing `FAQ$q1` to `FAQ$q2`, `FAQ$q3`. How can I do this?

```
for(i in 1: 19){
  yes <- table(FAQ$q1)[1]
  no <- table(FAQ$q1)[2]

  b <- barplot(table(FAQ$q1),
          main="Did you have any difficulties using the chatbot?",
          ylab="Count",
          names.arg = c("yes", "no"),
          col="blue",
          ylim = c(0,28))
  abline(v=c(1.3) , col="grey")
  text(b, y=c(yes+1,no+1), paste("n: ", c(yes,no) , sep=""), cex=1, col = "red")
}
```

Comment: Use `paste` and extract using `[[` instead of `$` i.e. `FAQ[[paste0("q", i)]]`

Comment: If your q1, q2, q3, are the same values, it returns the same output

Comment: you can check the plot by saving it to pdf  or change the `par` settings to show all the plots on the same window i..e `pdf("yourfile.pdf")` before the loop.  and then afterwards `dev.off()` or use `par(mfrow = c(5, 4))` etc to show on console

Comment: Yes, this works! if you write this out as an answer, i can accept it! if you could also explain during this answer what the difference is between paste and paste0

Comment: Thanks, posted as a solution.  The difference is in the `sep` argument.  In `paste0` it is `""`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `paste` to create a string for the column name and extract with `[[` (as `$` will try to match literally).  If we want to redirect the plots to a single pdf, then write the plots to `pdf`.  In the code, `table` function was applied on the same column multiple times, instead, do it once and create an object ('tbl1') which is reused as necessary

```
pdf("path/to/file.pdf")
for(i in 1:19){
  colnm <- paste0("q", i)
  tbl1 <- table(FAQ[[colnm]])
  yes <- tbl1[1]
  no <- tbl1[2]

  b <- barplot(tbl1,
          main="Did you have any difficulties using the chatbot?",
          ylab="Count",
          names.arg = c("yes", "no"),
          col="blue",
          ylim = c(0,28))
  abline(v=c(1.3) , col="grey")
  text(b, y=c(yes+1,no+1), paste("n: ", c(yes,no) , sep=""), cex=1, col = "red")
}
dev.off()
```

The difference in `paste0` and `paste` is in the `sep`.  By default `paste` uses `sep = " "` where as it is `""` in `paste0`